# Equivalent of php_value under Apache + php-fpm

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

under Apache + PHP as **module** you can set

```
php_value post_max_size 8M
```

inside a .htaccess.

How can I do this under Apache + PHP-FPM?

I'm using the FastCgiExternalServer directive, but want to keep the functionality within the .htaccess file (if possible).

Thank you!

Comment: This HowTo describes the use of the `php-fcgi-starter` which probably is what you are looking for: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-debian-lenny-p2

Comment: You can't. Find another way to solve the problem (multiple fpm process pools, code it in PHP)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found an somewhat elegant way to do it: [.user.ini files](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

It seems to be the .htaccess version for PHP-FPM.

Comment: Basically, this is the best option to control several PHP ini directives. However, many of those can't be controlled via .user.ini files. See the [list of directives](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php): all those tagged with PHP_INI_SYSTEM require different approach as given in other answers. And though you could set those via global php.ini using approaches via environment variables enables to have fine-grained control over those options depending on current virtual host, request method, request URL etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work recursively like .htaccess does for folders and files underneath the folder where the .htaccess is located. At least not when there is no php file located at the folder level.

Comment: That's right.
The .user.ini is part of php-fpm,
unlike .htaccess that is part of apache.
When no php file is requested, php-fpm would not be called.

Answer (score 23):

You can use

```
SetEnv PHP_VALUE "post_max_size = 8M"
```

or

```
SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "post_max_size = 8M"
```

in the apache configuration.

Comment: What is the difference between those 2?

Comment: php_value can be used in .htaccess and in Apache configuration. php_admin_value can only be used in Apache configuration and cannot be overwritten by your application (e.g. .htaccess or PHP-File)

Comment: Careful, this will set the value globally and not just for the site you're working on.  Multiple values will also overwrite each other.

Comment: @Sarke I had to stumble over that issue myself, so here is the proper link for anybody else: https://serverfault.com/a/817905/217271 ... looks like PHP/FPM doesn't help with reducing load on servers eventually.

Comment: This answer gave me the courage to move over to `php-fpm`. However, it caused some serious errors with some settings. `SetEnv` has the effect of setting global values which are not always correct for all my virtual hosts. In particular, a missing file caused `php-fpm` to over react and crash. This is better suited to settings which apply globally. For site-specific settings, `.user.ini` works better.