# Enable display_errors in .htaccess using `php-fpm` execution mode?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

When PHP is executing in `cgi` or `mod_php` mode, we can disable error reporting in `php.ini` and enable it on a per-directory basis using a `.htaccess` file in any directory we want.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors 1
php_flag display_errors 1
php_flag html_errors 1
php_value error_reporting -1
```

Doing it in the php script script itself is useless because it breaks on php parse errors which are very common.

How can I do the same thing when running `php-fpm` execution mode? Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265082/equivalent-of-php-value-under-apache-php-fpm might point you in a helpful direction, but not sure.

Comment: I know it's not your question, but it is a problem. Please consider using a better editor, because I have a parse error at most once per year using phpstorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using fpm PHP scans for a ini file in each directory

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Default is .user.ini

You should be able to put the same config in there but with the same syntax as php.ini:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
html_errors = 1
error_reporting = -1
```

Comment: Cool thanks a lot - works great! I figured out the syntax and added it to your answer.